# disconnect visual studio solution from sourcesafe?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe

I'm working on a project for a firm that has their main solution in sourcesafe.  The other developers are working like beavers on new stuff, and I'd like to be able to download the source from VSS, then disconnect it.  So I can get up to speed on the code without risk of bothering anyone else's code.

Is it possible to do this?  Many thanks if so.

-Larry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [How to Remove Version Control Bindings from Visual Studio Solutions](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42714?trk=DXRSS_DOTNET) at devx.com:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio, and delete all the files in the solution directory that end with .scc.
2. Edit the solution to remove all traces of the source code controller binding. Remove the section GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl) in the solution file. Also remove the keys named SccProjectName, SccLocalPath, SccAuxPath, and SccProvider.

Answer (score 10):

It's been a while since the scary days of source safe, but i believe this is what you have to do. In Visual Studio, go to File -> Source Safe -> Change Source Control (?). It'll open up a new window and list projects under current solution bound to Source Safe. Select the project you want to remove and click 'Unbind' at the top. It'll remove source safe bindings from the project. If you have to bind again, just click 'Bind' and select the location in the repository to bind to.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just make a [branch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y90e01b4(VS.80).aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

To unbind the  solution/Project from VSS:

1. In Visual Studio, open Solution Explorer and select a solution or project to unbind.
2. On the File menu, click Source Control, then Change Source Control.
3. In the Change Source Control dialog box, click Unbind.
4. Click OK.